# JSon seralization error with Web Api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, httpclient

I was getting a self referenceing loop error "Self referencing loop detected for property 'ApplicationInstance' with type 'ASP.global_asax'" returned from a PUT call to a web api.

I added this to the web api config:

```
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.All;
```

Now I get a different error:

"The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8 
InnerException":ExceptionMessage":"Error getting value from 'ReadTimeout' on 'System.Web.HttpInputStream'.","ExceptionType":"Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException","StackTrace":" at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue(Object target)...

Per suggestion, I added the ".ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;" config. This fixesd the loop  error, but not the 'can't read value' error.
I am having some trouble finding a cure for this one.

EDIT - Error is gone.  I am hesitant to say yet if it is fixed, because I am not yet sure why the error was there in the first place.  I made the error leave by changing my Put code in the web api.  It was:

```
    [HttpPut]
    public IHttpActionResult Put([FromBody]RecipientDTO recipient)
    {
        try
        {
            repo.SaveUpdatedRecipient(recipient);
            return Ok(this.GetById(recipient.RecipKey));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

and is now:

```
    [HttpPut]
    public HttpResponseMessage Put([FromBody]RecipientDTO recipient)
    {
        try
        {
            repo.SaveUpdatedRecipient(recipient);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.ToString();
            //ValidationMethods.GetDbValidationExceptions(ex);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
    }
```

I am still working on the error handling portion, but at least the error is gone and the data is saved.  I will update when I find out more. Any input is welcome.

Comment: If you try with this: GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatte r.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

Comment: thanks, but no change.

Comment: What does your PUT call look like?

Comment: Don't understand it either but your changing to HttpResponseMessage  did it for me too. 


I've always been iffy about IHttpActionResult helpers but its the first time I've had this issue with it. "Feels" like a specific version of the Newstonsoft jsonserializer  is bugging out somewhere in the Response chain.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the issue add the below line of code to WebApiConfig.cs file in your webapi project

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```